# How to handle try and exception in python for bucket list empty

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to handle not none or empty list exception while using boto3. I want to know is there any good way of pythonic code to write this.

```
buckets_list= None
try:        
    my_region = os.environ['AWS_REGION']
    if my_region == 'us-east-1':
        try:
            s3 = boto3.client('s3')
            buckets_list = s3.list_buckets()
        except Exception as err:
            logging.error('Exception was thrown in connection %s' % err)
            print("Error in connecting and listing bucket{}".format(err))
        if buckets_list['Buckets']:
            # Search for all buckets.
            for bucket in buckets_list['Buckets']:
            # my code follow to get other things...
            
        else:
            print("Buckets are empty in this region")
    else:
        print("Region not available")
        raise Exception("Exception was thrown in Region")    

except Exception as err:
    logging.error('Exception was thrown %s' % err)
    print("Error is {}".format(err))
    raise err
```

Is this the right way or any suggestions would help.

Comment: Does boto returns any particular exception in this scenario ? If yes, then you could narrow down "Exception" to something more specific.

Comment: If you want to check if the list is empty you can just `if buckets_list['Buckets']` and it wont go into the if statement if its empty. Iterating over a empty list with isn't an issue either is that's what worries you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `else` block of the try except suite. It is useful for code that must be executed if the [try clause does not raise an exception](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

```
try:
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    buckets_list = s3.list_buckets()
except Exception as err:
    logging.error('Exception was thrown in connection %s' % err)
    print("Error is {}".format(err))
else:
    # This means the try block is succeeded, hence `buckets_list` variable is set.
    for bucket in buckets_list['Buckets']:
        # Do something with the bucket
```

One issue I am seeing from your code is that, if the `list_buckets` call is failed there is a chance to get `NameError` at the line `if buckets_list['Buckets'] is not None:`. Because `buckets_list` is undefined if the `buckets_list` call is failed. To understand this try to run the following snippet :)

```
try:
    a = (1/0)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

print(a)
```

***UPDATE***

This is how I would implement this,

1. Use `.get` method to avoid `KeyError`
2. Use `else` block of the `try` `except` suite to specify the code must be executed if the try clause does not raise an exception.

```
my_region = os.environ.get('AWS_REGION')
if my_region == 'us-east-1':
    try:
        s3 = boto3.client('s3')
        buckets_list = s3.list_buckets()
    except Exception as err:
        logging.error('Exception was thrown in connection %s' % err)
        print("Error in connecting and listing bucket{}".format(err))
    else:
        buckets_list = buckets_list['Buckets']
        if not buckets_list:
            print("Buckets are empty in this region")
        else:
            # Search for all buckets.
            for bucket in buckets_list:
                pass
                # Do something with the bucket
else:
    print("Region not available")
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to change the logic

Comment: @Mia See my edit

Comment: do we don't need to add try block before my region at the first line.?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is somewhat not detailed enough, at least the beginning of the function should have been shared. Anyway, did you consider:

```
 try:
          s3 = boto3.client('s3')
         buckets_list = s3.list_buckets()
         print("buckets_list", buckets_list['Buckets'])
    
        print("Error is {}".format(err))
         if buckets_list['Buckets'] is not None: ##Here I am trying to check if buckets are empty
        # Search for all buckets.
        for bucket in buckets_list['Buckets']:
     (your other codes)


except Exception as err:
        logging.error('Exception was thrown in connection %s' % err)
```